# groovy. сумма значений цикла

Tags: json, groovy

Есть скрипт на groovy, который парсит JSON.
Я с большего добился того, что мне нужно, но дальше ума не хватает.
Вот скрипт:

```
<config xmlns="http://web-harvest.sourceforge.net/schema/1.0/config" scriptlang="groovy">

<var-def name="jsonData">
  <http url="https://pub_demo.s3.amazonaws.com/trainings/bakery.json"/>
</var-def>

<script><![CDATA[

        import com.google.gson.JsonObject
        import com.google.gson.Gson
        import com.google.gson.JsonArray
        import com.google.gson.JsonElement
        import com.google.gson.JsonParser
        import com.google.gson.JsonPrimitive
        import groovy.json.JsonSlurper

        println("jsonData wrapped object : " + jsonData.getWrappedObject());


        JsonArray items = new Gson().fromJson(jsonData.toString(), JsonObject.class).getAt("bakery");
        JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();

         for (int i = 0; i < items.size(); i++) {
             JsonElement value = items.get(i).get("name");
             JsonElement batters = parser.parse(items.get(i).get("batters").toString());
             JsonArray batter = batters.getAsJsonArray("batter");
             JsonArray topping = items.get(i).get("topping");

             println("\n\n\n"); 
             println("batter - " + batter);
             println("topping - " + topping);
             println("\n\n\n");

         break
         }

         for (int i = 0; i < items.size(); i++) {
              JsonElement ppu = items.get(i).get("ppu");

              println("ppu - " + ppu);  
              println("\n");

         }


]]></script>

    <export include-original-data="true"></export>

</config>
```

А вот лог на выходе

```
17:35:40 [INFO] VarDefProcessorValidated starts processing...
17:35:40 [INFO]     HttpProcessor starts processing...
17:35:41 [INFO] Downloaded: https://pub_demo.s3.amazonaws.com/trainings/bakery.json, mime type = application/javascript, length = 1852B.
17:35:41 [INFO]     HttpProcessor processor executed in 689ms.
17:35:41 [INFO] VarDefProcessorValidated processor executed in 694ms.
17:35:41 [INFO] ScriptProcessor starts processing...
jsonData wrapped object : [{
    "bakery": [{
            "id": "0001",
            "type": "donut",
            "name": "Cake",
            "ppu": 0.55,
            "batters": {
                "batter": [{
                        "id": "1001",
                        "type": "Regular"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "1002",
                        "type": "Chocolate"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "1003",
                        "type": "Blueberry"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "1004",
                        "type": "Devil's Food"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "topping": [{
                    "id": "5001",
                    "type": "None"
                },
                {
                    "id": "5002",
                    "type": "Glazed"
                },
                {
                    "id": "5005",
                    "type": "Sugar"
                },
                {
                    "id": "5007",
                    "type": "Powdered Sugar"
                },
                {
                    "id": "5006",
                    "type": "Chocolate with Sprinkles"
                },
                {
                    "id": "5003",
                    "type": "Chocolate"
                },
                {
                    "id": "5004",
                    "type": "Maple"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": "0002",
            "type": "donut",
            "name": "Raised",
            "ppu": 0.55,
            "batters": {
                "batter": [{
                    "id": "1001",
                    "type": "Regular"
                }]
            },
            "topping": [{
                    "id": "5001",
                    "type": "None"
                },
                {
                    "id": "5002",
                    "type": "Glazed"
                },
                {
                    "id": "5005",
                    "type": "Sugar"
                },
                {
                    "id": "5003",
                    "type": "Chocolate"
                },
                {
                    "id": "5004",
                    "type": "Maple"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": "0003",
            "type": "donut",
            "name": "Old Fashioned",
            "ppu": 0.55,
            "batters": {
                "batter": [{
                        "id": "1001",
                        "type": "Regular"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "1002",
                        "type": "Chocolate"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "topping": [{
                    "id": "5001",
                    "type": "None"
                },
                {
                    "id": "5002",
                    "type": "Glazed"
                },
                {
                    "id": "5003",
                    "type": "Chocolate"
                },
                {
                    "id": "5004",
                    "type": "Maple"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}]




batter - [{"id":"1001","type":"Regular"},{"id":"1002","type":"Chocolate"},{"id":"1003","type":"Blueberry"},{"id":"1004","type":"Devil's Food"}]
topping - [{"id":"5001","type":"None"},{"id":"5002","type":"Glazed"},{"id":"5005","type":"Sugar"},{"id":"5007","type":"Powdered Sugar"},{"id":"5006","type":"Chocolate with Sprinkles"},{"id":"5003","type":"Chocolate"},{"id":"5004","type":"Maple"}]




ppu - 0.55


ppu - 0.55


ppu - 0.55


17:35:42 [INFO] ScriptProcessor processor executed in 871ms.
17:35:42 [INFO] ExportPlugin starts processing...
17:35:42 [INFO] ExportPlugin processor executed in 7ms.
17:35:42 [INFO] Configuration executed in 1580ms.
17:35:42 [INFO] -------------------------------------------
17:35:42 [INFO] EXECUTION SUCCEEDED
17:35:42 [INFO] -------------------------------------------
```

Подскажите пожалуйста. Как мне вывести колличество topping и сумму ppu.

Answer (score 0):

```
        if (value.toString() == "\"Cake\"") {
          toppingLength = topping.size();
        }
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]